# Liquibase for cmd files

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, mercurial, liquibase

Need some sophisticated thing - somehow like Liquibase, but not for DB. We have many *.bat files, that need to be executed per each release on PROD. Problem is that only new and updated files should be executed, others shoud be avoided.

Is there some thing to do that? Thanks!

Comment: This question is off topic, software recommendations don't belong on SO.

Comment: I have no idea what's liquibase, but what you describe sounds like good old make utility.

Comment: [Java Batch](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html) or [Spring Batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch)